# How to parse a DiagnosticReport from a JSON and print the same JSON again?

Tags: java, json, report, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm parsing a DiagnosticReport from a JSON file and It works fine, but when I try to print the same JSON file throught IParser encode function, the JSON is different to the original. I need to print the same JSON.

Original JSON (String json)

```
    {
  "resourceType": "DiagnosticReport",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
    "div": "<div><p><b>Narrative A</b></p></div>"
  },
  "contained": [
    {
      "resourceType": "Patient",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "resourceType": "Observation",
      "id": "2",
      "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2017-03-22T22:00:28.089-05:00"
      },
      "text": {
        "div": "<div><p><b>Narrative B</b></p></div>"
      },
      "comment": "a comment"
    }
  ],
  "status": "appended",
  "code": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "code": "Report01"
      }
    ]
  },
  "subject": {
    "reference": "#1"
  },
  "effectiveDateTime": "2017-03-22T22:00:28-05:00",
  "issued": "2017-03-22T22:00:28.070-05:00",
  "result": [
    {
      "reference": "#2"
    }
  ]
}
```

First step is parse and the second step is encode and print

```
DiagnosticReport report = parser.parseResource(DiagnosticReport.class, json);
String encodeJSON = parser.encodeResourceToString(report);
System.out.println(encodeJSON);
```

And the result is different because the ***text*** tag in the **Observation** **is not showed**

```
{
  "resourceType": "DiagnosticReport",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><p><b>Narrative A</b></p></div>"
  },
  "contained": [
    {
      "resourceType": "Patient",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "resourceType": "Observation",
      "id": "2",
      "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2017-03-22T22:00:28.089-05:00"
      },
      "comment": "a comment"
    }
  ],
  "status": "appended",
  "code": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "code": "Report01"
      }
    ]
  },
  "subject": {
    "reference": "#1"
  },
  "effectiveDateTime": "2017-03-22T22:00:28-05:00",
  "issued": "2017-03-22T22:00:28.070-05:00",
  "result": [
    {
      "reference": "#2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**I'm trying this because I have a DiagnosticReport generated by my software and I need print it completely in a JSON file.**

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not legal to have narrative in a contained resource, nor is it legal to have meta/lastUpdated.  There are invariants that prohibit both.  Ideally, the parsing software should have thrown an exception, but it's not overly surprising that the serializer has trouble serializing content that's not supposed to be there.

Look at dom-1 and dom-4 in [dstu3](http://build.fhir.org/domainresource.html#invs) or [dstu2](http://hl7.org/fhir/dstu2/domainresource.html#invs)